# Octagonal Kurotto

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction

This is a Kurotto puzzle.

Rules of Kurotto:

> - Shade some cells to form connected groups of shaded cells.
> - Circled cells are unshaded. If they have a number in them, that number tells you the sum of the sizes of adjacent groups.

An example Kurotto puzzle (on a square grid), and its unique solution:

[image][image]

---

(In this puzzle, both squares and octagons can be shaded, and each square or octagon counts as a single cell for the number clues.)

[image]

Comment: Can you tell me why there are two occurrences of a circled cell labelled with a zero being adjacent to an unlabelled circled cell? I would have thought it redundant. If not, I don't fully understand the rules.

Comment: @theonetruepath Yes, those are redundant - they're there for clue symmetry purposes rather than being required to solve the puzzle.

Comment: Beautiful puzzle, Deusovi! Incredible! :D

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That was fun. Here's the solution:

> [image]

The key step that revealed how a lot of things had to be was

> finding that the 21-group from bottom left had to extend all the way up to the 24-cell at top right.

Comment: Great job! Btw how to come up with the deduction of 21-group?

Comment: @athin There is not enough space for the 24 in the top right to not be connected to the 21-group from the bottom left.